# Allow outgoing connections only to specific domain/IP

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to allow connection to only one website (for only one domain). For example www.mywebsite.com, with IP address A.B.C.D.

My iptables definition looks like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d A.B.C.D --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Problem is that it looks like subfolder of that website is not on the same server. So if it's on www.mywebsite.com, user must be able to access also to 
www.mywebsite.com/cobiss/, www.mywebsite.com/cobiss?param1=value1&param2=value2.

Can you help me what additional rules I need to allow access to related parts of that site?

Comment: It's imposible. There is not way to have a different folder in a diffent server. May be the site has more than one IP address asigned. I agree with @serg, if you want to filter HTTP properly, use Squid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work with `iptables` alone. The `iptables` works on OSI layer 3+4. You are looking for layer 7 filtering.

I suggest you set up a proxy server for filtering. I can recommend [Dans Guardian](http://dansguardian.org/) for web content filtering. Configure your firewall to redirect all web traffic over your web proxy (creating a transparent proxy) and then filter there.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/dansguardian-content-filtering-with-transparent-proxy-on-ubuntu-9.10-karmic) howto get started.

Answer (score 1):

do you try to filter outgiong traffic?

If you wand to control user access from you intranet to internet sites you must use SQUID proxy server, not firewall.

Comment: You will not be able to do that with squid alone. Since the blacklist mechanism of squid is for urls/ips only (if i remember correctly). You have to have *real* content filtering. Plus there are other proxys out there, not only squid.

Comment: can i use some parental control application? i tried with gnome nanny, but it can not start...